# Reading/ Extracting specific elements from XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I've got a really large and very complex XML file, I only want to extract very specific elements from it. The only elements I would like to retrieve are the Atcocode, NaptanCode, all of the elements in the Descriptor, the Longitude and Latitude from Translation and timing status and bus stop type from Stop classification.

I know VS can automatically generate a class, but this will parse unnecessary details. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Minimal**

Snippet from XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NaPTAN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.naptan.org.uk/" CreationDateTime="2018-03-22T08:59:00" ModificationDateTime="2018-03-22T08:59:00" Modification="new" RevisionNumber="0" FileName="NaPTAN030.xml" SchemaVersion="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.naptan.org.uk/ http://www.naptan.org.uk/schema/2.1/NaPTAN.xsd">
  <StopPoints>
    <StopPoint CreationDateTime="2009-07-01T16:36:00" ModificationDateTime="2015-11-03T16:19:00" Modification="revise" RevisionNumber="3" Status="active">
      <AtcoCode>030028280001</AtcoCode>
      <NaptanCode>brkpjmt</NaptanCode>
      <Descriptor>
        <CommonName>Tinkers Corner</CommonName>
        <Landmark>adj Forbury Lane</Landmark>
        <Street>Holt Lane</Street>
        <Indicator>opp</Indicator>
      </Descriptor>
      <Place>
        <NptgLocalityRef>E0053849</NptgLocalityRef>
        <LocalityCentre>0</LocalityCentre>
        <Location>
          <Translation>
            <GridType>UKOS</GridType>
            <Easting>439773</Easting>
            <Northing>165685</Northing>
            <Longitude>-1.42979961186</Longitude>
            <Latitude>51.38882190967</Latitude>
          </Translation>
        </Location>
      </Place>
      <StopClassification>
        <StopType>BCT</StopType>
        <OnStreet>
          <Bus>
            <BusStopType>CUS</BusStopType>
            <TimingStatus>OTH</TimingStatus>
            <UnmarkedPoint>
              <Bearing>
                <CompassPoint>NW</CompassPoint>
              </Bearing>
            </UnmarkedPoint>
          </Bus>
        </OnStreet>
      </StopClassification>
      <StopAreas>
        <StopAreaRef CreationDateTime="2009-07-01T16:46:00" ModificationDateTime="2009-07-01T16:46:00" Modification="new" RevisionNumber="0" Status="active">030G58280001</StopAreaRef>
      </StopAreas>
      <AdministrativeAreaRef>064</AdministrativeAreaRef>
    </StopPoint>
...
```

For example this was the C# class I had in mind:

```
class Naptan
    {
        public string AtcoCode { get; set; }
        public string NaptanCode { get; set; }
        public long Latitude { get; set; }
        public long Longitude { get; set; }
        public string TimmingStatus { get; set; }
        public string BusStopType { get; set; }
        public string CommonName { get; set; }
        public string Landmark { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Indicator { get; set; }
    }
```

**Complete**

[Link to the whole XML file in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16G4Neas8B9RY0gpG71ZRsxoAo_LOhk9v/view?usp=sharing)

Currently, I've tried this approach of turning it into a JSON file and then parsing it into a class, and then manually looping through a list of the objects and generating a new list of objects condensed from the original class.

[Current code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tISQ0cKLI9YVaRvLWkUU_AHWTus-dsbC/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT**

I've implemented Prateek Deshmukh method, however this doesn't extract the specific elements as asked for so I also had to add in this new code, which I would like to avoid doing, does anyone have any better suggestions?:

```
NaPTAN tempRawData;
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NaPTAN));
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"F:\DfT1.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    tempRawData = (NaPTAN)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
                }

                foreach (var StopPoint in tempRawData.StopPoints)
                {
                    Locations.Add(StopPoint.AtcoCode, new Naptan()
                    {
                        NaptanCode = StopPoint.NaptanCode,
                        Latitude = StopPoint.Place.Location.Translation.Latitude,
                        Longitude = StopPoint.Place.Location.Translation.Longitude,
                        TimmingStatus = StopPoint.StopClassification.OnStreet.Bus.TimingStatus,
                        BusStopType = StopPoint.StopClassification.OnStreet.Bus.BusStopType,
                        CommonName = StopPoint.Descriptor.CommonName,
                        Landmark = StopPoint.Descriptor.Landmark,
                        Street = StopPoint.Descriptor.Street,
                        Indicator = StopPoint.Descriptor.Indicator
                    });
                }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: I've now tried to update the question, I've attached the code I currently have, but I'd like to avoid using that method completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<Naptan> atcoCodes = doc.Descendants(ns + "StopPoint").Select(x => new Naptan()
            {
                AtcoCode = (string)x.Element(ns + "AtcoCode"),
                NaptanCode = (string)x.Element(ns + "NaptanCode"),
                Latitude = (double)x.Descendants(ns + "Latitude").FirstOrDefault(),
                Longitude = (double)x.Descendants(ns + "Longitude").FirstOrDefault(),
                TimmingStatus = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "TimingStatus").FirstOrDefault(),
                BusStopType = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "BusStopType").FirstOrDefault(),
                CommonName = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "CommonName").FirstOrDefault(),
                Landmark = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Landmark").FirstOrDefault(),
                Street = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Street").FirstOrDefault(),
                Indicator = (string)x.Descendants(ns + "Indicator").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    class Naptan
    {
        public string AtcoCode { get; set; }
        public string NaptanCode { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string TimmingStatus { get; set; }
        public string BusStopType { get; set; }
        public string CommonName { get; set; }
        public string Landmark { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Indicator { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[CS class](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ge23HFpZ33Iw7toS3WrctCpp8JD4CsSK)

Are you looking for such solution? Please see the class it has de-serialized the object

```
NaPTAN result = (NaPTAN)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, however I'd like to parse the data into a class and use them as a list of objects. So I need to be able to use them in the program, not just in the debugging view.

Comment: @Jamestrod , I have just shown the data into the code, you can access table from dataset object and form the class by selecting the table and the row,columns of the data. Debugging view was just to show the read datatable.

Comment: @Jamestrod, I have added the CS class and parsed the whole object instead of using Json. Can you please review if you are looking for same?

Comment: I've edited the question, while this does work, it requires manual extraction of the information, which seems like a lot of wasted resources, as its parsing the whole file.